# List of Games With Special Features on Audio (Not Music)

Tags: game, gameaudio

Hi, I wanted to ask if anyone is interested in creating a list here with all the computer/video Games they know of that include special features/short documentaries on sound design/audio implementation - much like are sometimes included with DVD films.

So here are some I can think of:

Deus Ex: Human Revolution - Augmented Edition comes with a documentary on the making of the game which includes a section on audio & music.

Elder Scrolls: Oblivion Special Edition comes with a DVD that included a making of documentary - which included audio.

ANyoen who wants to add to the list please do so!

Cheers.

- Si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's allot of this sort of stuff in online dev diary's. Search for sound or audio over at gametrailers.com and you'll find loads.

Comment: nice one will do :)

Answer (score 1):

Limbo

Plenty of research on the game audio of limbo (Martin Stig Andersen)